# Should a dummy VISA Credit Card be accepted in QA environment?

Tags: payment, credit-card, payment-processing, balanced-payments, credit-card-track-data

I'm using a dummy Visa Card  (Card Number: 4929804357275739 / Expiry Date: 08/22 / CVV: 249) for QA testing. I'm able to pay with a dummy card, and the transaction is authorized. In Production environment it isn't because it is used the RapidConnection for payments validation.
Should the transaction be un-authorized also from QA side?
Or this validation mechanism only makes sense to test in a real environment, for production?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general across the payment platform world test/qa/sandbox mode accepts any
card number that passes the luhn algorithm.  This prevents you from being forced to use live account numbers in test mode.

Test systems generally aren't connected to the actual payment processor,  although sometimes they are in test mode, but even then you can send dummy account numbers